# Solving the bezier curve equation is giving wrong value

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

[image]

Solving the bezier curve for $x,y=181,188$ given $p1=67,324$ and $p2=190,318$ and $p3=174,63$ and $p4=292,58$ using the below diagram for formula reduction I am using the $t$ for $x=181$ is coming to $t=1.41745...$ and the y calculated given $x=181$ and $t=1.41745...$ is $y=218$ and not even close to $188$ which is the value I am expecting close to it not so far from it.

I am only interested in real roots solutions for $y$ given $x$ and the start end and control point coordinates.

$px = 181, \qquad p1x = 67, \qquad p2x = 190, \qquad p3x = 174, \qquad p4x = 292$

$py =$ trying to solve for this

$p1y = 324, \qquad p2y = 318, \qquad p3y = 63, \qquad p4y = 58$

To supply context I am trying to figure out if the user mouse clicked the bezier curve.  So I thought solving for the y given the above picture equations for the x mouse click coordinate and checking if the resulting y is close enough to the corresponding mouse click y would show the user having clicked the bezier curve.

The equations in the diagram are reduced to where a computer can calculate it atm.  If the real roots of the cubic equation are incomplete please give the correct formulas for all the real roots of the cubic equation.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: $t$ must be in range $[0, 1]$. Don't you have other roots ? And where is $x$ (or $y$) in your equation ?

Comment: px is given in the equation reduction px = 181 solving for t with it gives t = 1.41745... solving for y given t is coming up with 218

Comment: are the equations i am using at least right

Comment: Can you check if the formula in the picture are right way to go about this

Comment: Lemme rephrase the question how about how can i solve the cubic equation x^3 + a * x^2 + b * x + c = 0 if the solution given in the diagram is correct the results for t^3 equation is resulting in out of range value for t which means something is wrong in the way I am solving for t given x, start, end and control point 1 and control point 2 coordinates.

Comment: Please consider putting all your formulas in the text (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/269624)) and leaving only the plot as a picture

Comment: The cubic for $x$-coordinate 
gives $253t^3-357t^2+309t-94$,
which has one real root $t\approx 0.4796671938$,
hence $y\approx 198.5664695$.

Answer (score 0):

From the parameters given at the bottom of the post and the cubic equation in the picture, we obtain the equation:

$$273 t^3 - 417 t^2 + 369 t - 114 = 0$$

Which has a single real solution:

$$t \approx 0.497607953114642$$

The exact form in radicals is too long to write here, I refer the OP to Wolfram Alpha, which I used.

Here's the link:

`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(292-3*174%2B3*190-67)+t%5E3%2B3(174-2*190%2B67)+t%5E2%2B3(190-67)+t%2B67-181%3D0`

Comment: What I need is the equation for t how did the number 0.49 arrived at

Comment: @AkshaySrinivasan, the cubic equation is written in my answer. I'm not going to write the whole solution. Wolfram Alpha gives an answer in radicals, you can look it up using the link. You already know how to solve cubic equations, as evident from your post. If you really need a full solution, you can do it yourself, and then check that the answer you get is the same as this one

Comment: I subscribed to see the step by step solution and paid but am unable to sign in lol their sign in functionality is broken on wolframalpha.com

Comment: @AkshaySrinivasan, I'm not able to help you with that, sorry. I have no affiliation with Wolfram, I only use their free functionality. Write to the support

Comment: Ok was able to sign in to wolframalpha.com and the steps are well not what i am looking for i was hoping for a simple set of programmable equations

Comment: Maybe I can supply context i am trying to see if the user clicked the given curve so I thought with the equations in my diagram i can solve for y given an x and check if the resulting y is close enough to the mouse y coordinate in which case the user clicked the bezier curve

Comment: @AkshaySrinivasan, you can add it to your post, insead of writing a comment here

Comment: Also the equations to solve for the real roots I got from this site from a post

Answer (score 0):

https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/

This answers how to solve for t in the cubic then its plug and chug

Comment: actually in code this doesnt work at all sigh

Comment: the first post was working partially not for all curves in code

Comment: ok so i got a workaround but now i am more curious.... i can use experimental cutting edge firefox path2d() and isPointInStroke() with my mods tricks out of my hat lineWidth to maximize within my reason the stroke path to get approximation on the hit but the very fact that it works says to me those in the top of numerical methods applied software land firefox and google chrome maybe are in possession of the solution and are not coughing up the math the numerical methods I will busta that shit without brute force within my reason time because firefox is open source i can hunt that code down

Comment: i can reverse engineer it i can put it in plain sight javascript any brain dead commodity developer worldwide cant understand time is ticking challenge is cough up the math its been done yesterday in firefox dont make me reverse engineer your ass ez mode i prefer higher results when my intelligence is involved... yes drunk so more brutally honest still thinking about it have to why no solution lol